# Java parse string to date

Tags: java, date

I'm trying to parse a string to date object in Java.
My string is: `String date = 2013-04-13 21:00:00;` 
The code is:

```
    String myFormatString = "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss";
    Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormatString, Locale.ENGLISH).parse(date);
    System.out.println(date1);
```

I'm expecting the output to be: `Sun Apr 13 21:00:00 GMT+00:00 2013`
but what I get is: `Sun Jan 13 21:00:00 GMT+00:00 2013`

Can you see why?

Comment: You're mixing month and minutes. Month should be using M not m. And hour should be using H for 24 hours.

Comment: Months start from 00, not 01. `Jan = 00, Feb = 01, Dec = 11`. Don't expect Apr for 04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Months are represented by "M", "m" is for minutes.

```
String myFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
```

Detailed information is on [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).